# how, using retrofit2, confirm a GET request with a certificate (root -> ca -> my)

Tags: java, ssl, retrofit, retrofit2, tls1.2

I need to send a GET request and confirm it (authentication) with a certificate (my). The certificate has this chain (root -> ca -> my).
How to use the retrofit2 library to implement this?

For rage,

1) The handshake is established, but does not authenticate, returns error 302 (without additional messages).

2) there is a cUrl library, as far as I know, there is a CURLOPT_SSLCERT method into which you shove the certificate.

connectionSpec initialization:

```
connectionSettings = new TlsConnectionSettings(keyStoreProvider.getKeyStore());
```

__

```
public TlsConnectionSettings(KeyStore keyStore) {
    setTrustManagerFactory(keyStore);
    setSslContext();
}   

public ConnectionSpec getSpec() {
    return new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
            .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_0)
            .cipherSuites("TLS_CIPHER_2012", "TLS_CIPHER_2001", "SSL3_CK_GVO_KB2")
            .build();
}

private void setTrustManagerFactory(KeyStore keyStore) {
    try {
        trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(
                Provider.KEYMANGER_ALG,
                Provider.PROVIDER_NAME
        );
        trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void setSslContext() {
    try {
        sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance(
                Provider.ALGORITHM,
                Provider.PROVIDER_NAME
        );

        sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), new java.security.SecureRandom());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch ( Exception e){

    }
}
```

Retrofit client initialization:

```
 public void init(String baseUrl, TlsConnectionSettings connectionSpec) {

    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);


    OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(interceptor);


    if (connectionSpec != null) {
        client
                .connectionSpecs( Collections.singletonList(connectionSpec.getSpec()))
                .sslSocketFactory(connectionSpec.getSocketFactory(), connectionSpec.getTrustedManager())
                .connectTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(40,TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
    }


    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://" + baseUrl)
            .client(client.build())
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

}
```